# Shortly after startup on Ubuntu Studio 18.04, mouse slows down - seems like something graphics related

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, keyboard, mouse

So here's my problem.  I just freshly installed Ubuntu Studio 18.04.  Everything great.  The mouse moves smoothly.  But then 7 to 8 seconds after startup (after the desktop is visible) the system becomes extremely sluggish.  Most obviously sluggishness is the mouse.  Keyboard typing is also lacking responsiveness.

Because the system functions just fine during the first 7 seconds, I hypothesize that some command during the startup routine, 7 seconds into startup, is triggering the sudden sluggishness.  I've tried researching.  I've reinstalled NVidia drivers multiple times.  Doesn't work.  I don't think it's the drivers because as I said, the mouse moves perfectly fine during the first 7 seconds.  Any ideas?

Thank you.